# precise event timing in linux/java

Tags: java, asynchronous

I am writing a game in Java that does some machine learning in the background for procedural generation, and I want it to escape briefly from the backgrounded training routine after `n milliseconds` to render the frame and update the NPCs and so on.

The key thing being that `n` CANNOT be overestimated, as the game needs to be frame-locked to 16ms on all capable hardware and rendering stuff in lgwjl is a balancing act itself.

The problem is that `System.nanoTime()` doesn't seem to work in my environment (it results in timeouts several orders of magnitude smaller than intended; HPC timers are incredibly flaky in my experience).  And `System.getCurrentTimeMillis` doesn't seem to have well-specified rounding behavior, which means it could overestimate by nearly a millisecond, which is unacceptable.

Does anybody know if there is a good way to do this?

Comment: Why does your question not involve threading?  It seems like the ML stuff should be going on on a different thread and if you did that, the rendering wouldn't necessarily have to interrupt the background processing.

Comment: Found this, which recommends LockSupport.parkNanos.  Dunno if it is any better, though   http://www.sagui.org/~gustavo/blog/code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to have a lot of pain doing this.  What you're describing is essentially the context switching an operating system (or the JVM, in Java's case) is supposed to abstract away from needing to work with directly.

Instead, you should have one thread for processing business logic, and a wholly separate thread for managing and updating the display.  These two threads then communicate through a controller which either runs in its own thread or in the same thread as the business logic thread, depending on the complexity of your data transfer.  This concept is called the [Model-View-Controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and [many, many articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=java%20model%20view%20controller) have been written on how to best implement it.

By separating these behaviors you can have your business logic run continuously without needing to be interrupted, and your view thread can be very simple, essentially looking like the following:

```
while(true) {
  long initTime = curTime();
  // this will refresh the GUI and also show any new data from the controller
  refresh(); 
  sleep(curTime()-initTime);
}
```

Now of course the meat of your question, I think, is this magic `sleep()` method I call above.  I pass it the amount of time spent updating so it can subtract that from the total desired sleep time, however the question of how to ensure the time spent actually sleeping is highly precise is more complicated.

You say `System.nanoTime()` is imprecise in your environment, and unfortunately that may very well be a dealbreaker for you.  `System.nanoTime()` is going to be providing the most granular elapsed-time data your OS/processor is publishing, and so if this method isn't providing the data you need, your machine / JVM may not be able to provide the granularity you need.

Major game/simulation developers face this same problem, and have long since resolved it by eliminating the requirement of exact frame update times because it is simply too complicated to attempt to line up processing time with real-world time in any reliable manner (suppose, for instance, the OS halted your program for several milliseconds, such that processing the next frame would take longer than the allowed time, what would you do?).

Instead, the general goal of visualizations like games and simulations is to calculate the model's most up-to-date state it can, and allow the view to query for new information whenever possible.  Consider the following table:

```
| Time | Model | Slow View | Med. View | Fast View |
|    1 |     1 |         1 |         1 |         1 |
|    2 |       |           |           |         1 |
|    3 |     3 |           |           |         3 |
|    4 |       |           |         3 |         3 |
|    5 |     5 |           |           |         5 |
|    6 |       |         5 |           |         5 |
|    7 |     7 |           |         7 |         7 |
|    8 |       |           |           |         7 |
|    9 |       |           |           |         7 |
|   10 |    10 |           |        10 |        10 |
|   11 |       |        10 |           |        10 |
|   12 |    12 |           |           |        12 |
|   13 |       |           |        12 |        12 |
|   14 |    14 |           |           |        14 |
|   15 |       |           |           |        14 |
|   16 |    16 |        16 |        16 |        16 |
```

Here we're seeing an arbitrary unit of time passing (the most precision available on the system) a model which calculates its state for a given time as quickly as possible, and views which attempt to display the most up-to-date state it has available.  The faster the view can run, up to the speed of the model, the more visually smooth the view will appear, if the view runs faster than that, it's not really a problem, though it doesn't get any smoother.  But no matter what, from the user's perspective the state of the model is updating in real time.

The key insight here is to have your model calculate the state for a given instant of time, whatever that value might be, rather than to attempt to make your model run at any sort of exact rate, which is essentially impossible on shared hardware.

Comment: Excellent answer overall, I'll mark it as correct.  MVC is not particularly compelling, though; I've never heard of it used in a game, and it doesn't make sense to divide this particular application so rigidly into "business logic" and "rendering logic" since the rendering needs a lot of data from the other subsystems every single frame.  For the offline stuff, though, I'm pretty sure I can keep one fast and several slow threads up, and hand off graph objects from one thread to another once the weight updates are finished. And I can just queue tasks onto the slow threads from the fast one.

Comment: MVC, or at least something following the pattern of compartmentalizing logic from display, is industry standard just about *everywhere*.  Mixing your model and view is a recipe for pain down the road.